# How to get session by country, session by device and active user in laravel?

Tags: laravel, google-analytics

I would like to display few things in dashboard. I am using Spatie to get data from google analytics.

I have research but unable to find a solution for this.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

You can get info from Google Analytics with performQuery method. This example for 1 week.

```
$analyticsByCountry = Analytics::performQuery(
    Period::days(7),
    'ga:sessions',
    [
        'metrics' => 'ga:sessions',
        'dimensions' => 'ga:country'
    ]
);

$analyticsByBrowser = Analytics::performQuery(
    Period::days(7),
    'ga:sessions',
    [
        'metrics' => 'ga:sessions',
        'dimensions' => 'ga:browser'
    ]
);

$analyticsByActiveUsers = Analytics::performQuery(
    Period::days(7),
    'ga:users'
);
```